# How to remove ligatures from a font using FontForge

Tags: fontforge

I have a font with some ligature errors in it. This is causing problems in [my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089334/custom-font-gives-incorrect-glyph-for-certain-letter-combinations-in-android). I want to just remove the ligatures. How do I do that in FontForge?

This question is related but it is going the other way.

- [Fontforge Scripting how to add ligatures for a glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902593/fontforge-scripting-how-to-add-ligatures-for-a-glyph)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/) go to **Element > Font Info > Lookups > GSUB**. You should be able to select a ligature table there. Then you can click **Delete** to delete all the ligatures or **Edit Data** to choose which ligatures to delete.

[image]

After pressing **Edit Data** you can select specific ligatures. Click **Delete** to remove them.

[image]

Comment: +1, removed bad ligatures from a monospace font (Google's Noto Sans Mono) :) How to improve the answer? It could be confusing that to export the font you don't click `File` + `Save` but `File` + `Generate Fonts` instead, and I got some errors/warnings that I could just skip and get a working font with the ligatures stripped.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work on all fonts. Some are missing some meta files and then the lookup option is disabled for the font. :/